# How does Inter VLAN routing block work?

Tags: networking, routing, mikrotik-routeros

I have VLAN10 for Admin and VLAN20 for Office on different subnet. Currently they are automatically routed by router. I want admin to be able to access office stuff but do not want office to be able to access admin stuff.

I created a firewall blocking vlan office to admin. But this confuses me, will admin still be able to access office? Shouldn't it be two way agreement? Let's say admin intitiate connection to office but office not able to respond back, technically admin cannot talk to office as well.

I am using mikrotik with following rule 
`/ip firewall filter add chain=forward action=drop in-interface=vlan-20 out-interface=vlan-10 comment="Block Office to Admin"`

Answer (score 1):

> But this confuses me, will admin still be able to access office?

Depends on other rules present in the chain. With only this rule, no.

> Let's say admin intitiate connection to office but office not able to respond back, technically admin cannot talk to office as well.

So you need to allow *only* responses in this direction. There are two ways for that... It's easiest to make use of RouterOS stateful firewall, which keeps track of which packets belong to which connections. Add a forward rule which allows packets by their *state*:

```
connection-state=established,related action=accept
```

Remember that firewall rules are processed from top to bottom, so you need to pay attention to the order they're placed in. The specific accept rules will only work if they're placed before the blanket deny rule.